# Start/Stop Thread Java

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium

I'd like to start/stop a thread when I click a button.

Here is what I tried to do.

```
Thread thread;
String c = classMain.classes.get(a);
Class c1 = Class.forName(c);
Method ref = c1.getMethod("ref");

Object rex = c1.newInstance();
thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {   
            running = true;
            ref.invoke(rex, null);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
if (isRunning() == true) {
    System.out.println("Here");
    running = false;
    thread.interrupt();
    thread.join();
} else {
    thread.start();
}
```

For some reason `interrupt()` and `join()` don't stop the thread.

What should I do? Am I missing something?

*EDIT*

Alright, so I found a quick and dirty solution for this: throw a custom exception.

I'll explain better:

Instead of `thread.interrupt()` and `thread.join()`, I launch a reflected  method called `interrupt`.

It launches an exception, that makes the Thread collapse, thus instant termination.

I am not sure whether this is efficient or not (I have to say that the method I call is a test made with Selenium, and theoretically, it should not waste resources when closed like this), so if you know more let me know.

Comment: what is the call to **isRunning()**? The thread you created will either be started or it will be interrupted and joined which does nothing since the thread is not started.

Comment: @DanielFigueroa oh sorry, thought that was obvious. isRunning() gives me the current status of the bool `running`.

Comment: Well that's what I thought but if you look at your code, and assuming that all the code belongs in the same block, that is that you haven't copied and pasted your code from different parts. Then **isRunning()** will always return false.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read up on what `join` and `interrupt` do.

`join` just wait's for the thread to finish, `interrupt` just sends the interrupt signal to the thread, which normally does nothing, it will only work if the thread is waiting for some IO or similar. The interrupt signal is normally used to shut down a thread, but it is entirely up the the thread to check for it and shut down properly if it is received. Your question does not give enough detail about what is going on in your second thread to tell if this should work.

If you for some reason cannot change the code run in the thread to make it listen to `interrupt` you can use `Thread.stop` instead. It is however deprecated since using it can be dangerous since it is prone to causing deadlocks. The Javadoc for [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) links to several excellent resources on the subject.

Also note that it is illegal to `start` a thread more than once, which seems like what you are trying to do. You will instead need to recreate it. (as in calling `new Thread` and `start` again.)

Comment: Well then how should I interrupt it?

Comment: Yeah but doesn't `Thread.suspend` just suspend it? I'd like to kill it completely

Comment: As in `stop`ing it such that it can not be restarted again?

Comment: The method called `interrupt` is supposed to kill it, but there may be a delay.  When you call `interrupt`, the thread continues until it reaches a point such as a `sleep` or a `wait` when it can stop what it's doing.  At that point, it throws an exception, and if the program has been written properly, that should result in the thread ending.   My feeling is that this answer hasn't really described that accurately.

Comment: Yeah, exactly .

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem so what should I add to the method that I'm calling?

Comment: That is entirely up the the thread. In most cases interrupt will not shut down a thread.

Comment: See my edited answer, I originally misunderstood what you were trying to do

Comment: Doesn't work either. I am trying another route. Because I use selenium, I'm currently trying to find a way to stop execution in the middle. Currently I haven't found anything. Also `System.quit(1)` kills the whole process so it's useless.

Comment: If it's a selenium thing then I can't help you. My answer should work for normal java. I would suggest tagging the question selenium, or writing a more open question about what you are trying to do on a slightly higher level. You might get more helpful answers that way.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem There is no 'supposed' about it. The method `interrupt()` is supposed to *interrupt* it. What the thread does about that, if anything, is entirely up to it, and, again, there is no correctness requirement that says it should shut down. You are making all this up. Please don't.